# Do I have to write GRE to apply to physics PhD programs in the US?

Tags: phd, physics

I'm doing my Masters in GRAPPA at University of Amsterdam now and I want to apply to multiple places for PhD after I'm done.

However, the applications in US confuse me. Some say they want GRE scores, some don't and some say it's optional even. And since I'll be applying to some places in Europe as well, I don't want to write GRE and Subject GRE if it isn't that mandatory.

I'm sorry if this might be a duplicate question but any link/explanation would be helpful.

Comment: You mention duplicate question, so which other questions have you read / considered already?

Comment: @SolarMike I haven't read anything here particularly but I almost assumed that this is probably a frequent question. I found other similar websites discussing this but none of them were very helpful.

Comment: A quick search on here gives : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/33023/72855  and that's only one of many which might, or might not, help you...

Comment: My experience has been that GRE scores are typically needed to get into Grad School. That is, when going from either a Bachelors to Masters or directly from Bachelors to PhD. However if you already have a Master's, then I would think that the result of that Masters program would be much more relevant, and hence I doubt that many places would really require the GRE. However, every place is different and there definitely could be schools that still require it

Comment: @bremen_matt Yeah, that's the problem. There's no fixed rule so I think it's just better to have everything. That seems better than my application not being considered at all.

Comment: Doing the GREs is going to be a hassle. It is something you should prepare for for a few weeks ahead. Then you will have to find a place to take the test, and pay a lot of money. If I were you, I would contact the schools that you want to apply to and explain your situation.

Comment: @bremen_matt Yeah, it's definitely going to be a hassle. There are no test centers in the Netherlands which means the nearest test center is either in Germany or France. 

Another problem is that I've lost touch with some areas of Physics since I'm doing a very specialized course now. So writing the Subject GRE will also not be as easy.

But I think that's what I'll finally do, contact the schools and explain the situation and see what that leads to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every university in the US has its own policies. There is no national educational system in the US.

If you want to apply to a place for which it is mandatory then it is mandatory. Otherwise not. However, for those places for which it is optional it might be a way to bolster your application, so consider that, at least.

Every graduate school is looking at your application materials for evidence of success. If you can show that and also meet the rules then you have a chance to be admitted. But the rules aren't normally optional.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that makes sense. It's probably a better idea to have all possible things on my application and maximize the chances of acceptance. Thanks!